# Fluent Ribbon SelectedTabItem or SelectedTabIndex

Tags: wpf, mvvm, ribbon, fluent, fluent-ribbon

I'm using Fluent Ribbon in a MVVM design pattern, with a View/ViewModel. My goal is to change the body according to which tab is selected. I could use either SelectedTabItem or SelectedTabIndex and lookup the corresponding view. However, neither fire when the tab selection changes. In the View I have...

```
<Fluent:Ribbon Grid.Row="0" SelectedTabItem="{Binding SelectedRibbonTab}" SelectedTabIndex="{Binding SelectedRibbonTabIndex}">
</Fluent:Ribbon>
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding RibbonTabContent}"/>
```

In the ViewModel I have...

```
    // Used both Item and Index for troubleshoothing, but need only one or the other for implementation

    private IDictionary<string, FrameworkElement> RibbonTabViews;
    private List<FrameworkElement> RibbonTabViewsList;

    public RibbonTabItem SelectedRibbonTab
    {
        get 
        { 
            return selectedRibbonTab;
        }
        set
        {
            Update(() => SelectedRibbonTab, ref selectedRibbonTab, value, false);
            UpdateContentControl();
        }
    }

    public int SelectedRibbonTabIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return selectedRibbonTabIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            Update(() => SelectedRibbonTabIndex, ref selectedRibbonTabIndex, value, false);
            UpdateContentControl(value);
        }
    }

    public FrameworkElement RibbonTabContent
    {
       get { return ribbonTabContent; }
       set { Update(() => RibbonTabContent, ref ribbonTabContent, value, false); }
    }

    protected void UpdateContentControl()
    {
        RibbonTabContent = RibbonTabViews[SelectedRibbonTab.Header.ToString()];
    }

    protected void UpdateContentControl(int index)
    {
        RibbonTabContent = RibbonTabViewsList[index];
    }
```

I know I don't need both bindings but for the sake of troubleshoot I have both Item and Index. I would think in the ViewModel SelectedRibbonTab and SelectedRibbonTabIndex would be called each time the tab changed. Unfortunately, that doesn't appear to be the case. I have breakpoints at the setters and getters for each and neither are hit when changing tabs. What am I missing? I've been using this approach for years with Microsoft Ribbon but for some reason these don't fire in Fluent Ribbon. Any help would be great, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the binding mode to `TwoWay` to get updated values in your ViewModel.